# How Do I Use args In advanced command handlers (files)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have recently started to move my commands into files too keep them organised. I am having a problem where that the default g!help command works, but any with an argument e.g g!help staff just sends the same message as g!help. (All the code in index.js is fine).

Here is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "this is help command",
    execute(message, args){
            if (args[1] === 'staff'){
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ("Staff Commands:")
                .addField ("**g!mute <user> <time>**", "Will mute the user for the specified amount of time. **PLEASE REPORT WHY YOU MUTED PERSON IN** #mute-people")
                .setColor(0xfc8e08)
                message.channel.send(embed);
            }else
            if (args[1] === 'krunker'){
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ("Krunker::")
                .addField ("**g!profile**", "Will give you a link to my Krunker.io profile")
                .addField ("**g!trade**", "Will Display the t&c for trading")
                .addField ("**g!clan**", "will give the link to my Clan [G3O]")
                .addField ("**g!scope**", "will give the scope I made/use")
                .addField ("**g!overlay**", "will give overlay I made/use")
                .addField ("**g!hitmarker**", "will give the hitmarker I made/use")
                .addField ("**g!mod**", "will give the mod I made")
                .addField ("**g!settings**", "will give the settings I use")
                .setColor(0xfce808)
                message.channel.send(embed);
            }else
            if (args[1] === 'socials'){
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ("Socials:")
                .addField ("**g!twitch**", "Will give you a link to my Twitch")
                .addField ("**g!yt**", "Will give the link to my Youtube Channel")
                .addField ("**g!twitter**", "will give the link to my Twitter")
                .addField ("**g!instagram**", "will give the link to my Instagram")
                .addField ("**g!tiktok**", "will give the link to my TikTok")
                .addField ("**g!socials**", "will give the link where you can find all of my socials")
                .setColor(0xfc0808)
                message.channel.send(embed);
            }else{
                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ("Commands List:")
                .addField ("**g!help socials**", "Will give you a list of commands for my socials")
                .addField ("**g!help staff**", "Will give a list of commands for STAFF ONLY")
                .addField ("**g!help krunker**", "Will give a list of commands all realted to Krunker")
                .setColor(0x01B8FF)
                message.channel.send(embed)
        
            }
    
    }
   }
```

Comment: Like nintendo pointed out, probably just args[0] instead of args[1], next time you should log what args is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small mistake, you are checking for args[1] instead of args[0].

Comment: Thanks Guys, The Problem is Solved